# List of images as subpart in Typo3

Tags: typo3

At current I'm making a list of images for a banner slider using code as follows:

```
page.10.marks.topimage = IMAGE
page.10.marks.topimage {
    file.import.data = levelmedia: -1, "slide"
    file.import = fileadmin/user_upload/    
    file.import.override.field = media
    file.import.current = 1
    file.import.listNum = 0
    border = 0
    file.height = 670
    file.width = 1800
    altText = Banner
    titleText = Banner
    wrap = <div id="slides">|
}

page.10.marks.topimage1 = IMAGE
page.10.marks.topimage1 {
    file.import.data = levelmedia: -1, "slide"
    file.import = fileadmin/user_upload/    
    file.import.override.field = media
    file.import.current = 1
    file.import.listNum = 1
    border = 0
    file.height = 670
    file.width = 1800
    altText = Banner
    titleText = Banner
}

etc...
```

However, this means, every time the other admins want to add a new slide or remove one from the total count, I have to change this code. Adding the content of the slides is not a problem, they simply upload to user_upload and it pulls 0 to 3 at current. However, they want to be able to upload 5 images and have it show 5 or just 3 and have it show 3 and I need a more `dynamic` way to implement this. I'm still new to Typo3 (i really don't understand it, php is 10,000X easier!), so if anyone could, please explain to me better than the docs, how subparts work or what my solution might be.

And no I can't just write an `extension` to do it. Been there and tried that and still can't figure out how to get extensions in without breaking it.

FYI, if you could break it down and help me "like" it, that would be great, because at current, I'd rather they use wordpress or joomla or ANYTHING but this. If you've seen my other questions, then you'll realize, i've had 0 fun working with this cms and mostly because the documentation and/or "help" i've received has been almost completely useless to me. I only mention this so that maybe someone will break this down for me like i break down jquery/php/.net questions for others. It doesn't hurt to be polite and show a nub "step-by-step" instructions!

Comment: And yes, I know some of you are reading this and already getting ready to neg me and barrage me for my negativity of typo3, as you have with previous questions. But if just one of you would stop hating and actually "explain" it to me without being a complete jerk, perhaps I might actually begin to change my mind about this thing

Comment: Note on your negativity: If you kick a bee hive, you cannot expect the bees to give you honey but some stings. :-) Simply leave the emotions out of your question and concentrate only on the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Note on your "i really don't understand it, php is 10,000X easier!": That assumes that the person building the website is a PHP programmer. IMHO, in TYPO3 it is presumed that there is higher division of roles in the team building the website and that the person setting up the site is not a programmer and programmers are only given jobs of programming extensions.

Comment: @cascaval Then explain why a building full of programmers and IT people cant figure this out any better than me. Everything is falling on me because i'm the only one making it work and do "anything". But quite literally, about 20 people here who can write drives, apps, program in everything from DOS to VB.Net, and almost no one here can make since of it. Also, as for the previous, I've tried leaving emotions out, all i got was "crap" answers and a bunch of "i'm better than you" type comments along with alot of downvoting but no explanation as to why.

Comment: Fact is, the is nothing special about typo3 and if it wasn't for one Board members arrogant mistake, we wouldn't even be dealing with this. But people in this community who do work with typo3, have presented themselves to me in a manner most unbecoming and thus the reason for my long retort at the end of this question.

Comment: Well, I obviously do not know why those 20 people cannot figure it out but one possible reason which I mentioned to you in some previous question of yours is that programmers often treat Typoscript as a programming language which it is not. Think of it as something similar (though more complex) to Apache configuration. You don't have to be (and you are not expected to be) a programmer to setup Apache and even though its configuration has some programming features like conditions, it's just a configuration. The same applies to Typoscript.

Comment: As for the help you have got from local community - hopefully this question will start a new trend for you. :-) @maholtz is always coming up with very good answers and there's plenty of other people here who know a lot about TYPO3. However, probably none of them wants to deal with some emotional melodrama. Just saying. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
page.10.marks.topimage = TEXT
page.10.marks.topimage {
  # retrieve data
  data = levelmedia: -1, "slide"
  override.field = media
  # we have some filenames in a list, let us split the list
  # and create images one by one
  # if there are five images selected, the CARRAY "1" will be executed
  # five times where current is loaded with only one filename
  split {
    # the images are separated via ","
    token = ,
    # you can do funny stuff with options split, f.e. if you want to give first
    # and last image a different class... but thats another topic;)
    # we just say, render every splitted object via CARRAY "1"
    cObjNum = 1 
    1 {
      # just render the single image, 
      # now there should be one filename in current only
      10 = IMAGE
      10 {
        file.import.wrap = fileadmin/user_upload/|
        file.import.current = 1
        border = 0
        file.height = 670
        file.width = 1800
        altText = Banner
        titleText = Banner
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: OMG, this was perfect and thank you so much for the explination! The only thing it was missing was to add `wrap = <div id="slides">|</div> ` at the end of `page.10.marks.topimage {`. I've not yet tested adding or removing images from the uploads, but this one call seems to wrap up everything I was doing in 3 to 4 so I'm assuming it will work. The other admins will put it to the test later, i'm taking a celebration break! Thank you so MUCH!

Comment: If I could ask you one more question, I've been racking my brain about. They want to be able to add "links" on "specific" images, not all of them. I have no idea where to even start using typoscript this way. I thought about just going through the content.php, but I know there has to be a better solution. Can you point me in the right direction? Does typoscript even have an "if" statment of sorts? and if so, would i have them attach the link to the image upload somehow, or place the links somewhere else to pull from? I assume something along the lines of `typolink.parameter` will be needed?

Comment: If it helps to answer my last question any, (and i ddnt design this originally) the "banner images" are "uploaded" via the "Resources" of the main page. I see an area for "Title" and "Caption" on each one, but I don't see a way to add a link, unless maybe they could place it in "Caption" and perhaps I could use that as the "data" to make it a link via javascript on page load or something.

Comment: Well, perhaps you can get more into TypoScript by reading http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptIn45MinutesTutorial/ - which TYPO3 version do you use? I guess 6.1? Please create just a new questions, it is not so easy to explain within comments. And there is a "if" statement, because you can only decide if something should be rendered, or not. For your task, you will need perhaps stdWrap, COA, append, required and data.

Comment: i've read that doc. it was partly how i got as far as i have. and i will post a second question soon. going on lunch atm. TY for all your help